# Start remote PowerShell command and have it finish even if disconnected

Tags: powershell

If I start a remote PowerShell session with:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName somecomputer
```

Then I want to execute a long-running process:

**`[somecomputer]: PS C:\>`** `C:\SomeApp\DoSomething.exe`

If my remote session is disconnected for whatever reason - such as a local machine network outage or reboot - is there any way to ensure that the command still completes on the server?

From what I'm seeing, it seems to go away as soon as my PS session dies. I've also tried `Start-Process`, but it seems to behave the same.

I'm trying to run things on a server without having to RDP in. Still a beginner in PowerShell, so I'm sure there are plenty of things I'm missing. I'm on Win10, PowerShell 7, connecting to Windows Server 2016, but I assume it would be the same anywhere.

Comment: take a look at `Get-Help about_remote*` for some ideas. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I don't need a new session at all, just the correct syntax:

```
Invoke-Command `
-ComputerName somecomputer `
-AsJob `
-ScriptBlock {& 'C:\SomeApp\DoSomething.exe'}
```

The `-AsJob` parameter runs the command as a background service. The `-ScriptBlock` parameter lets me run an exe.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `New-PSsesion`

```
Enter-PSSession: Starts a temporary interactive session with a remote computer. You can have only one interactive session at a time using Enter-PSSession. Exiting the session destroys it.
```

```
New-PSSession: Creates a PERSISTENT connection to a local or remote computer. Exiting the session does not destroy it, it is still available to connect to again unless you do something like Disconnect-PSSession or it times out.
Furthermore, with New-PSSession you can assign the session a Name or to a variable for easier re-use, etc.
```